# how to get data from url with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to get data from an url with jquery

for example if you have `www.test.com/index.html?id=1&name=boo`

how to get id and name?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this. It's pure javascript, no jQuery involved. In fact jQuery is too heavy for such a job, really.

```
function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
        {
            return decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
        }
    }
}​

var id = GetURLParameter('id');
var name= GetURLParameter('name');
```

decodeURIComponent should be used to allow parameter value contain any character, for example the very crucial equals sign `=`, an ampersand `&` or a question mark `?`.

Comment: It's pure javascript - not jQuery.

Comment: @KrzysztofJabłoński - If you are using pure javascript look at the answer to which your question duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Comment: you are welcome and special thanks to you and @Tony for the help

Comment: another little question.. does this geturlparameter returns a string??? because i can't compare it in an if statement..

Comment: I just upvoted this answer because it was the solution to a problem I was looking for, but I don't know that it's accurate to say that jQuery can be too heavy for any job, imho.

Answer (score 1):

A simple one if you know the url always has `id` and `name`

```
var url = "www.test.com/index.html?id=1&name=boo";
var id = /id=(\d+)/.exec(url)[1];
var name = /name=(\w+)/.exec(url)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i have done complete solution for above issue. please check demo link as shown below:

For that, you have first include latest jquery.js and querystring-0.9.0.js scripting files in header tag.

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpac

**HTML**

```
<a href="#?param1=abc&param2=def">
  abc
</a>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var param1 = $.QueryString("param1");
            var param2 = $.QueryString("param2");
            alert(param1);
            alert(param2);
        }, 300);

    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpac

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Working fine in IE and chrome both.Get query string values through javascript

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
        var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
        if (results == null){
           return null;
        }
        else {
           return decodeURI(results[1]) || 0;
        }
    }

        var getData= $.urlParam('emailid');
```