# How to retain the background color of clicked bootstrap cards in a wizard type web pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here I am having the two steps of web pages each page consists of bootstrap cards. In the first page the user can select any one of the given cards and after clicking next the second web page the user can click any no.of cards now my requirement is even If I navigated to second page and click on previous the previously clicked card should retain its background color.
My overall codepen.io link
This is My JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#main_1').click(function() {
  $(".blue").removeClass("blue");
   $(this).addClass("blue");
 });
 $('#main_2').click(function() {
 $(".blue").removeClass("blue");
 $(this).addClass("blue");
 });
$('#main_3').click(function() {
  $(".blue").removeClass("blue");
  $(this).addClass("blue");

});
$('#main_4').click(function() {
  $(".blue").removeClass("blue");
  $(this).addClass("blue");
});
$('#main_5').click(function() {
  $(".blue").removeClass("blue");
  $(this).addClass("blue");
});
$('#main_6').click(function() {
  $(".blue").removeClass("blue");
  $(this).addClass("blue");
});
$('#main_7').click(function() {
  $(".blue").removeClass("blue");
  $(this).addClass("blue");
});
$('#main_8').click(function() {
  $(".blue").removeClass("blue");
  $(this).addClass("blue");
});
$('#main_9').click(function() {
  $(".blue").removeClass("blue");
  $(this).addClass("blue");
});

$("#room_1").click(function(){
       $("#room_1").toggleClass("blue")
});


$("#room_2").click(function(){
       $("#room_2").toggleClass("blue")
});
$("#room_3").click(function(){
       $("#room_3").toggleClass("blue")
});
$("#room_4").click(function(){
       $("#room_4").toggleClass("blue")
});
$("#room_5").click(function(){
       $("#room_5").toggleClass("blue")
});
$("#room_6").click(function(){
       $("#room_6").toggleClass("blue")
});
$("#room_7").click(function(){
       $("#room_7").toggleClass("blue")
});
$("#room_8").click(function(){
       $("#room_8").toggleClass("blue")
});
$("#room_9").click(function(){
       $("#room_9").toggleClass("blue")

});

});
```

The overall code and working link:

https://codepen.io/lakshmi123__/project/editor/XkBqaa

Comment: Try to use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for saving the date of previous color.

Comment: @Vaku thats what how can I do that? even I am trying it all the cards are being selected

Answer (score 1):

If I got your requirements right,

1. First page you make a selection, then you click next which is different HTML page, so its not same page with navigation in it.
2. You can click previous to come back to last page from home button
3. But as your using absolute links to navigate between these 2 pages(without passing any data), their is no way you can know what selection was made on last page.

What needs to be done is send some sort of data or create a cookie or something which will dictate the selection made.

With the provided codepen, simplest thing you can do is, change link of next button on page one, when selection is made to something like using jquery when selection is made

```
public2.html?id=main_2
```

then fetch it in jquery like below on page 2 and set back button link with the id after fetching this id from link, like above again

```
$(document).ready(function () {


/* var url = window.location.href; */
    var url = "www.test.com/page2.html?id=1";
    var id = /id=(\d+)/.exec(url)[1];
    console.log(id);
});
```

so link on back button will become

```
public1.html?id=main_2
```

Then when you go back to page1 get id from code same as above and make the selection ..

I hope you get the idea.. cannot really do all the code required

reference for fetching id from url, comment 2 
[how to get data from url with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456639/how-to-get-data-from-url-with-jquery)

Comment: @ Gursharn I am actually passing the data through local storage

Comment: which data ? when you say local storage what do you mean ? When you click next, does it go through any backend ? if yes which one ?

Comment: actually I was dynamically getting the card data from database on to my web page and on click I was sending the data from one page to another page via local storage But in the codepen I cant dynamically right

Comment: are you using something like setItem() getItem() those things ?

Comment: Yes I will send the link wait

Comment: https://codepen.io/lakshmi123__/project/editor/XkBqaa#0 see this link now and see local storage also once the items which I am clicking are storing

Comment: Ok few things I can notice for your rooms.js .. you are not calling "sample()" function on document ready, means even though data is there you won't get it, because ur function is not triggering, second why you need to have whole object as far I can use you can just set id in local storage and retrieve it. None the less I am not really fan of using local storages so may be try the solution I provided if it make sense, or try to clean ur code.

Comment: the sample() method is used in the other page its just not matter

Comment: well again my point is .. when you get to room.js page, you need to get this item on document ready which I don't see in the example provided

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205637/discussion-between-g-lakshmi-and-gursharn-singh).